# Using var to intentionally leak a variable

Tags: javascript

Is the following pattern ok in javascript, or is this frowned upon? And if the latter, what would be a better approach?

```js
function arithmetic_sum(n) {
    for (var [i, sum] = [0, 0]; i <= n; sum += i++);
    return sum;
}

console.log(arithmetic_sum(10));
// 55
```

Comment: It does not throw error, so it's _ok in javascript_

Comment: I don't see how the word "leak" has anything to do with the code here.

Comment: @Pointy as in, if it were `let` it wouldn't escape the block scope of the `for` loop.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well `var` has been there since the language was first developed, so what you wrote would be considered highly idiomatic code. You could of course declare the `sum` variable outside the loop, but it's more succinct as posted.

Comment: `var` is functionally scoped, so everything in the function body now has something called `sum` (and `i`) polluting the scope *ew*

Comment: This works with let: `function arithmetic_sum(n) { let i,sum; for ([i, sum] = [0, 0]; i <= n; sum += i++);  return sum; }`

Comment: @mplungjan It wont work, as sum is not available outside of the scope of for loop as it is defined with let

Comment: @AbhayPrince right but that's exactly what it is -- `let i, sum; for` is **before** the `for` loop.

Comment: @David542 Oh my bad. I missed it. Yeah you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is valid JavaScript.

Some people may like that, but it's a bit outdated and mixing old and new styles (var, but in combination with destructuring).

Also having code inside the interation clause of the for loop can be confusing.

I would prefer this instead:

```js
function arithmetic_sum(n) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(arithmetic_sum(10));
// 55
```

Comment: If you don't like the destructuring, you can still write the good ol' `var i=0, sum=0;` (which even is shorter).

Comment: The problem there is still the use of `var`

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the person to be honest. Some people will like this pattern because it makes the code shorter but in my personally opinion it makes the code harder to understand.

The reason this works is because of javascript hoisting. You can read more about this here.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Now, if you were to switch this code to use `let` this code would break.

I think its also important to understand how `var` differs from `let` & `const`.

This article explained the differences very good
https://medium.com/@codingsam/awesome-javascript-no-more-var-working-title-999428999994

I personally would write this code like this:

```
function arithmetic_sum(n) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) sum += i;
    return sum;
}


console.log(arithmetic_sum(10));
// 55
```

Comment: [MDN is a preferred resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: `for (var [i, sum] = [0, 0]; i <= n; sum += i++);`

will turn into this under the hood because of javascript hoisting

`var i; 
var sum;
for ([i, sum] = [0, 0]; i <= n; sum += i++);`

thats why your able to return `sum` without causing a error

Comment: `function arithmetic_sum(n) { let i,sum; for ([i, sum] = [0, 0]; i <= n; sum += i++);  return sum; }` works with let

Comment: Agreed @mplungjan but someone posted a question about how this had anything to do with javascript hoisting but they deleted their comment

Comment: `function arithmetic_sum(n) { let i,sum; for ([i, sum] = [0, 0]; i <= n; sum += i++);  return sum; }`

This works but personally I would argue this is hard to read. you only save 10 extra characters here might as well make this easier to read for the next person vs making the code shorter.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/long-code-vs-short-code/